# Angular 2 Cross Field Validation (model based) addErrors?

Tags: forms, validation, angular, form-control

I am implementing a cross field validation for two fields in a form (reactive / model based approach) and do not know how should I add an error to existing Error List of a formcontrol

Form:

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(3));
  city: new FormGroup({
    cityOne: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(3)),
    cityTwo: new FormControl('', Validators.minLength(3))
  }, this.validateEqualCities)
});
```

Validator:

```
validateEqualCities(formGroup: FormGroup) {
    return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
    if (formGroup.controls['cityOne'].value &&  formGroup.controls['cityTwo'].value && formGroup.controls['cityOne'].value !== formGroup.controls['cityTwo'].value) {

     formGroup.controls['cityOne'].setErrors({ 'equalCities': true }, { emitEvent: true });
     formGroup.controls['cityTwo'].setErrors({ 'equalCities': true }, { emitEvent: true });

        return { 'equalCities': false };

    } else {
      formGroup.controls['cityOne'].updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false });
      formGroup.controls['cityTwo'].updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false });
    }

    return null;
    };
  }
```

My Problem: 
If the validation fails "setErrors(..)" overrides all errors which are already there (Validators of formControls), so there is no correct state, because actually there should be 2 errors.

If I do not set errors to form controls directly and only return an error to the form, only the form is invalid and gets the error, but not its controls.

How can I achieve that both, form and controls has the real state of validation?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can capture the errors object as it is before you assign the errors, modify it, and write the entire object back.

```
validateEqualCities(formGroup: FormGroup) {
  return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
    if (formGroup.controls['cityOne'].value &&  formGroup.controls['cityTwo'].value && formGroup.controls['cityOne'].value !== formGroup.controls['cityTwo'].value) {
      let errors = formGroup.controls['cityOne'].errors ? formGroup.controls['cityOne'].errors : {};
      errors['equalCities'] = false;
      formGroup.controls['cityOne'].setErrors(errors, { emitEvent: true });

      errors = formGroup.controls['cityTwo'].errors ? formGroup.controls['cityTwo'].errors : {};
      errors['equalCities'] = false;

      formGroup.controls['cityTwo'].setErrors(errors, { emitEvent: true });

      return { 'equalCities': false };
    <...>
```

Here's a Plunker with a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/XTeH1ifQTJSoMvBEvE0d?p=preview

Comment: It looks good, I thought about the solution and asked myself it looks like some kind a hack, there is no other more elegant / native solution? But nevertheless, thank you!

Comment: Not really, there's no means to add a single error if you're doing an explicit set (and there's no way to make group applied errors cascade down that I'm aware of) so this is pretty much what you get.